# Автозамена символов в URL NGINX

Tags: php-nginx

Суть ситуации: есть множество url новых, отличаются от старых тем, что символ _ заменен на -

Конфигураций море.
Выяснил что редирект 301 делается при помощи

```
location uri {
}
```

с регулярками работать умею
проблема - перебор всех возможных вариантов url с нижним подчеркиванием на тире займет не одну сотню строк в конфигурационном файле nginx и то не факт что все варианты я учту

Вопрос - есть ли функция АВТОЗАМЕНЫ в nginx на подобии

```
location ~ \/(tyres|wheels)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/ {
  set $brand str_replace( '_', '-', $2 );
  set $model str_replace( '_', '-', $3 );
  return 301 /$1/$brand/$model/;
}
```

примеры url

```
/tyres/tri_ace/steady_33/
/wheels/m_and_k_forged_wheels/
/tyres/tri_ace/carrera/
```

Comment: Не location, а rewrite. Одной строкой.

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15912191/6817117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал по-своему, т.е. написал вариант для всех всевозможных и не возвозжных комбинаций

```
# заменяет в названиях брендов и моделей шин нижнее подчеркивание на тирэ
    location ~ ^\/(tyres|wheels)\/(([^_\/]+_.+)|([^_\/]+\/[^_\/]+_.+))$ {
    return 301 https://$host/redirect.php?data=$request_uri;
    }
# ---------------------
```

а в php написал

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if( !isset($_GET['data']) ) header('Location: /');
//header('Location: /');
$brand = '';
$model = '';
$result = preg_match( '/^\/(tires|wheels)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+\/)?(.*)?/i', $_GET['data'], $arr );
$brand = str_replace( '_', '-', $arr[2] );
$url = '/'.$arr[1].'/'.$brand;
if(isset($arr[3])){
    $model = str_replace( '_', '-', $arr[3] );
    $url .= '/'.$model;
}
if( isset($arr[4]) ){
    $url .= $arr[4];
}
header('Location: '.$url);
```